# Content assist with javaCompletionProposalComputer for Eclipse not working

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

Content assist with *org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.javaCompletionProposalComputer* for Eclipse not working.
'Code and Me' proposal is not visible

[Content Assist View Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVrWX.png)

I make same as described here but without success
http://codeandme.blogspot.com/2014/05/extending-jsdt-adding-your-own-content.html

As same as described at above link I do this

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?eclipse version="3.4"?>
    <plugin>
       <extension point="org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.javaCompletionProposalComputer"
       id="codeandme_category"
       name="Code and me proposals">
       <proposalCategory/>
     </extension>

 <extension
       id="codeandme_proposal"
       point="org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.javaCompletionProposalComputer">
   <javaCompletionProposalComputer
      class="com.codeandme.jsdt.contentassist.CustomCompletionProposalComputer"
      categoryId="com.codeandme.jsdt.contentassist.codeandme_category"
      activate="true">
   </javaCompletionProposalComputer>
 </extension>

</plugin>

    package com.codeandme.jsdt.contentassist;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposal;
import org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.text.java.ContentAssistInvocationContext;
import org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.text.java.IJavaCompletionProposalComputer;

public class CustomCompletionProposalComputer implements IJavaCompletionProposalComputer {

 @Override
 public void sessionStarted() {
 }

 @Override
 public List computeCompletionProposals(ContentAssistInvocationContext context, IProgressMonitor monitor) {

  ArrayList<CompletionProposal> proposals = new ArrayList<CompletionProposal>();

  proposals.add(new CompletionProposal("codeandme.blogspot.com", context.getInvocationOffset(), 0, "codeandme.blogspot.com".length()));
  proposals.add(new CompletionProposal("<your proposal here>", context.getInvocationOffset(), 0, "<your proposal here>".length()));

  return proposals;
 }

 @Override
 public List computeContextInformation(ContentAssistInvocationContext context, IProgressMonitor monitor) {
  return null;
 }

 @Override
 public String getErrorMessage() {
  return null;
 }

 @Override
 public void sessionEnded() {
 }
}
```

[Eclipse plugin view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yB5CF.png)

Anything missing or wrong?

Comment: That extension point is for Javascript completion proposals, not Java.

Comment: The `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaCompletionProposalComputer` extension point is used for Java completion proposals

Comment: Thx, I try it but has no effect. When I restart eclipse I got this error when I try 'tab + space' for code completion.
`The 'org.eclipse.mylyn.java.ui.LegacyJavaDocProposalComputer_all' proposal computer from the 'org.eclipse.mylyn..java-ui' plugin did not complete normally. Unable to instantiate the extension...`

Comment: You can't use any of the JSDT code, you must rewrite it all to use the JDT code

Comment: ok just solved, the dependency has to be changed too,
org.eclipse.jdt.ui